# Grouping multiple rows from an Oracle Table where two rows have few matching column values along with having similar related rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I have the below scenario, if you could please help me find the most optimal solution for this.

I have a Table with the below set of Rows:

### Script:

CREATE TABLE ASSETS (Asset_ID VARCHAR2(30), Item_Name VARCHAR2(240), Category VARCHAR2(30), Vendor NUMBER, Location_ID NUMBER, Unit_Price NUMBER, Quantity NUMBER);

```sql
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('100.000', 'CPU', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 1000, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('100.100', 'Mouse', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 50, 2);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('100.100', 'Keyboard', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 100, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('100.100', 'OS', 'Software', 10001, 12345, 200, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('100.100', 'Assemble', 'Install', 10001, 12345, 150, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('100.100', 'Shipping', 'Freight', 10001, 12345, 100, 1);


insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('101.000', 'Laptop', 'Hardware', 10002, 14567, 800, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('101.101', 'Mouse', 'Hardware', 10002, 14567, 50, 2);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('101.101', 'Keyboard', 'Hardware', 10002, 14567, 100, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('101.101', 'OS', 'Software', 10002, 14567, 200, 1);


insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('102.000', 'CPU', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 1000, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('102.102', 'Mouse', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 50, 2);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('102.102', 'Keyboard', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 100, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('102.102', 'OS', 'Software', 10001, 12345, 200, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('102.102', 'Assemble', 'Install', 10001, 12345, 150, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('102.102', 'Shipping', 'Freight', 10001, 12345, 100, 1);


insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('103.000', 'Laptop', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 1000, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('103.103', 'Mouse', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 50, 2);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('103.103', 'Keyboard', 'Hardware', 10001, 12345, 100, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('103.103', 'OS', 'Software', 10001, 12345, 200, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('103.103', 'Assemble', 'Install', 10001, 12345, 150, 1);
insert into Assets (Asset_ID, Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price, Quantity) values ('103.103', 'Shipping', 'Freight', 10001, 12345, 100, 1);
```

Post Insertion:

```
Col A       Col B       Col C       Col D       Col E       Col F       Col G
Asset_ID    Item_Name   Category    Vendor      Location_ID Unit_Price  Quantity
--------    ---------   --------    ------      ----------- ----------  --------
100.000     CPU     Hardware    10001       12345       1000        1
100.100     Mouse       Hardware    10001       12345       50      2
100.100     Keyboard    Hardware    10001       12345       100     1
100.100     OS      Software    10001       12345       200     1
100.100     Assemble    Install     10001       12345       150     1
100.100     Shipping    Freight     10001       12345       100     1

101.000     Laptop      Hardware    10002       14567       800     1   --Parent and Child Lines have different values for Location, Vendor etc.  
101.101     Mouse       Hardware    10002       14567       50      2   Also the Number of Child records are different than any other Asset.
101.101     Keyboard    Hardware    10002       14567       100     1
101.101     OS      Software    10002       14567       200     1

102.000     CPU     Hardware    10001       12345       1000        1   --All Parent and Child lines match with 100.00
102.102     Mouse       Hardware    10001       12345       50      2
102.102     Keyboard    Hardware    10001       12345       100     1
102.102     OS      Software    10001       12345       200     1
102.102     Assemble    Install     10001       12345       150     1
102.102     Shipping    Freight     10001       12345       100     1

103.000     Laptop      Hardware    10001       12345       1000        1   --Parent line has different Item_Name when compared to 100.00 and 102.00
103.103     Mouse       Hardware    10001       12345       50      2
103.103     Keyboard    Hardware    10001       12345       100     1
103.103     OS      Software    10001       12345       200     1
103.103     Assemble    Install     10001       12345       150     1
103.103     Shipping    Freight     10001       12345       100     1
```

Any Asset ID ending with `.0` is a Parent and items ending with `.1`, `.2` etc are its child records. So in the above data set, `100.0` is the Parent and `100.1`, `100.2` etc are considered its Child records.
The current requirement was to pull these records from the table based on the Asset ID, i.e fetch the Parent and its corresponding child records, send it across to an external system in a string in a predetermined format.

The Parent and its Child are being fetched using below script and put into a string as shown below.

```sql
DECLARE
    CURSOR Cur_Fetch_Asset IS
        SELECT A.*
          FROM ASSETS A
         WHERE Asset_ID LIKE '%.000';

    CURSOR Cur_Fetch_Child (p_in_parent_line   VARCHAR2,
                            p_in_child_line    VARCHAR2)
    IS
        SELECT A.*
          FROM Assets A
         WHERE A.ASSET_ID IN (p_in_parent_line, p_in_child_line);

    lv_child_inv_line_num   VARCHAR2(30) := NULL;
    lv_feature         VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;
    lv_asset           VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;
    
BEGIN
    FOR Fetch_Asset_Rec IN Cur_Fetch_Asset
    LOOP
        IF lv_asset IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            lv_asset :=
                   lv_asset
                || 'AS|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Item_Name
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Category
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Vendor
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Location_ID
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Unit_Price
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Quantity;
        ELSE
            lv_asset :=
                   'AS|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Item_Name
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Category
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Vendor
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Location_ID
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Unit_Price
                || '|'
                || Fetch_Asset_Rec.Quantity;
        END IF;

        SELECT    SUBSTR (Fetch_Asset_Rec.Asset_ID,
                          0,
                          INSTR (Fetch_Asset_Rec.Asset_ID, '.', 1) - 1)
               || '.'
               || SUBSTR (Fetch_Asset_Rec.Asset_ID,
                          0,
                          INSTR (Fetch_Asset_Rec.Asset_ID, '.', 1) - 1)
          INTO lv_child_inv_line_num
          FROM DUAL;

        FOR Fetch_Child_Rec
            IN Cur_Fetch_Child (Fetch_Asset_Rec.Asset_ID,
                                lv_child_inv_line_num)
        LOOP
            IF lv_feature IS NOT NULL
            THEN
                lv_feature :=
                       lv_feature
                    || 'AF|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Item_Name
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Category
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Vendor
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Location_ID
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Unit_Price
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Quantity;
            ELSE
                lv_feature :=
                       'AF|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Item_Name
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Category
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Vendor
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Location_ID
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Unit_Price
                    || '|'
                    || Fetch_Child_Rec.Quantity;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        lv_asset := lv_asset || lv_feature;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lv_asset: '||lv_asset);
    
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: '||SQLERRM);
            
END;
```

The new requirement now is to combine multiple Parent and Child records into a single Parent and Child line where

1. The Parent and Child records have same value of: Item_Name, Category, Vendor, Location_ID, Unit_Price
2. And the Parent should have the same number and type of child records.

So in the above data set, Asset_ID 100.00 and 102.00  satisfy both Point#1 and #2. They should be considered a single combined row as shown below before sending to the external system.
The Quantity would need be summed up when combining the similar lines.

```
Item_Name   Category    Vendor      Location_ID Unit_Price  Quantity
---------   --------    ------      ----------- ----------  --------
CPU     Hardware    10001       12345       1000        2

The Child records also would be combined with their matching child records and have the Quantity summed up.
Mouse       Hardware    10001       12345       50      4
Keyboard    Hardware    10001       12345       100     2
OS      Software    10001       12345       200     2
Assemble    Install     10001       12345       150     2
Shipping    Freight     10001       12345       100     2
```

Could you please let me know how Point#1 and 2 can be done either through SQL or PL/SQL?

Bit stumped on whether to use any Group By logic or Inner Joins or any combination.